# Can not install rails on Ubuntu 14.0.4. Gem install rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04

Im trying to install rails on ubuntu. Current version of ruby is 2.2.2 but its returning and error

omer@AK47:~$ gem install rails

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net" port 443 (https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.2.1.gemspec.rz)

Comment: Can you post the output of `gem install rails --debug -V`?

Comment: its a very long output, What shall I do?

Comment: Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLErrorWaitReadable' at /home/omer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182 - read would block

Comment: just keeps repeating this line again and again

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe your certificates are out of date? Try to fix them by `sudo update-ca-certificates`